# AmCharts: custom button to hide/show graph

Tags: amcharts

I would like to have my own buttons to hide/show lines on a linear graph.
The legend is fine, but I want my own HTML/CSS.
Is there a way to do this?
Attaching the hide/show event maybe?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the [`showGraph`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#showGraph) and [`hideGraph`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#hideGraph) methods from your buttons' events. Since they take the graph instance, you'll want to have access to the chart to pass in the desired graph instance either by accessing the `graphs` array directly or calling [`getGraphById`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#getGraphById) if you set ids for your graphs, then check the graph's [`hidden`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#hidden) property to know when to call `showGraph` or `hideGraph`

Assuming you have the graph index in your button's markup like `<button data-graph-index="0">Toggle first graph</button>`, you could do something like this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var graph = chart.graphs[e.currentTarget.dataset.graphIndex];
  if (graph.hidden) {
    chart.showGraph(graph);
  }
  else {
    chart.hideGraph(graph);
  }
});
```

Here's a demo:

```js
var chart;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-graph'),
  function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var graph = chart.graphs[e.currentTarget.dataset.graphIndex];
      if (graph.hidden) {
        chart.showGraph(graph);
      }
      else {
        chart.hideGraph(graph);
      }
    });
  }
);

chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataProvider": [{
        "year": 1994,
        "cars": 1587,
        "motorcycles": 650,
        "bicycles": 121
    }, {
        "year": 1995,
        "cars": 1567,
        "motorcycles": 683,
        "bicycles": 146
    }, {
        "year": 1996,
        "cars": 1617,
        "motorcycles": 691,
        "bicycles": 138
    }, {
        "year": 1997,
        "cars": 1630,
        "motorcycles": 642,
        "bicycles": 127
    }, {
        "year": 1998,
        "cars": 1660,
        "motorcycles": 699,
        "bicycles": 105
    }, {
        "year": 1999,
        "cars": 1683,
        "motorcycles": 721,
        "bicycles": 109
    }, {
        "year": 2000,
        "cars": 1691,
        "motorcycles": 737,
        "bicycles": 112
    }, {
        "year": 2001,
        "cars": 1298,
        "motorcycles": 680,
        "bicycles": 101
    }, {
        "year": 2002,
        "cars": 1275,
        "motorcycles": 664,
        "bicycles": 97
    }, {
        "year": 2003,
        "cars": 1246,
        "motorcycles": 648,
        "bicycles": 93
    }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "cars": 1318,
        "motorcycles": 697,
        "bicycles": 111
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "cars": 1213,
        "motorcycles": 633,
        "bicycles": 87
    }, {
        "year": 2006,
        "cars": 1199,
        "motorcycles": 621,
        "bicycles": 79
    }, {
        "year": 2007,
        "cars": 1110,
        "motorcycles": 210,
        "bicycles": 81
    }, {
        "year": 2008,
        "cars": 1165,
        "motorcycles": 232,
        "bicycles": 75
    }, {
        "year": 2009,
        "cars": 1145,
        "motorcycles": 219,
        "bicycles": 88
    }, {
        "year": 2010,
        "cars": 1163,
        "motorcycles": 201,
        "bicycles": 82
    }, {
        "year": 2011,
        "cars": 1180,
        "motorcycles": 285,
        "bicycles": 87
    }, {
        "year": 2012,
        "cars": 1159,
        "motorcycles": 277,
        "bicycles": 71
    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "gridAlpha": 0.07,
        "position": "left",
        "title": "Traffic incidents"
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "title": "Cars",
        "valueField": "cars"
    }, {
        "title": "Motorcycles",
        "valueField": "motorcycles"
    }, {
        "title": "Bicycles",
        "valueField": "bicycles"
    }],
    "chartCursor": {
        "cursorAlpha": 0
    },
    "categoryField": "year",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "startOnAxis": true,
        "axisColor": "#DADADA",
        "gridAlpha": 0.07,
        "title": "Year"
    },
    "export": {
     "enabled": true
     }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<button class="toggle-graph" data-graph-index="0">Toggle first graph</button>
<button class="toggle-graph" data-graph-index="1">Toggle second graph</button>
<button class="toggle-graph" data-graph-index="1">Toggle third graph</button>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was searching for, thank you so much!

Comment: amCharts 5:
`
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-graph'),
        function (button) {
            button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                var series = chart.series.values[e.currentTarget.dataset.graphIndex];
                if (series.isHidden()) {
                    series.show();
                } else {
                    series.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    );
`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its a version issue or a different way I was using the api, but the accepted answer hadn't worked for me. In fact chart.graphs itself wasn't defined.

All I was used was

```
chart.show()
```

and

```
chart.hide()
```

Background...

```
const [chart, setChart] = useState(null)

...

let newChart = root.container.children.push(
  am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
    panX: false,
    panY: false,
    wheelX: 'none',
    wheelY: 'none',
    layout: root.verticalLayout,
  })

setChart(newChart)
```

---

I also had some tooltips and modal dialogue (to show when the chart is empty)

```
const hideChartTooltip = () => {
    const tooltip = chart.series.getIndex(0).get('tooltip')
    if (tooltip) {
      tooltip.set('forceHidden', true)
      tooltip.hide()
    }
  }


useEffect(() => {

    if (!chart) {
      console.log('show/hide graph no-op')
      return
    }

    console.log(`chart view mode : ${isChartView}`)
    if (isChartView) {
      chart.show()
    }
    else {
      console.log('hiding the graph... ')
      hideChartTooltip()
      chart.hide()
    }

  }, [isChartView])
```

Ref: [Sprite - hide](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/sprite/#hide_method)

Inheritance hierarchy...

```
Chart <- Container <- Sprite
```