# amCharts: How to toggle series using external custom buttons instead of legends

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to implement toggle the graph series using custom html/css buttons instead of legends as per requirement.

This [AmCharts: custom button to hide/show graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909745/amcharts-custom-button-to-hide-show-graph)  is similar to my requirement but not working for me.

Currently, i'm using amCharts4

Please help me to handle this.

The following is the code I'm trying
I made char as global (var chart), if i'm using series hitting the error series is not defined even i'm making it var global

```
   <button onClick={this.handleSeries}>Series </button>
   /* <button class="toggle-graph" data-graph-index="0">Series1 </button> */

 handleSeries = (e) => {
    var graph = chart.graphs[e.currentTarget.dataset.graphIndex];
    if (graph.hidden) {
      chart.showGraph(graph);
    } else {
      chart.hideGraph(graph);
    }

    /*  if (series.isHiding || series.isHidden) {
      series.show();
    } else {
      series.hide();
    } */
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I followed the different approach without touching the graph or amChart legends.

I just used a boolean in the state and used if condition

```
if(this.state.booleanTrue){
show graphSeries logic
}
```

Here I just made the button as toggle

```
this.setState({ !this.state.booleanTrue })
```

This logic fulfilled my requirement.

Please mention if there is any other approach for this